# Regression analysis interpretation

Tags: regression, correlation, p-value, interpretation

In a regression correlation situation where $r=.2,\ p<0.05$, we can say that there is a weak relationship between the independent and dependent variable (as $r=.2$). Since p-value is significant, we can also mention that the independent var significantly support the predicted response variable. What is the role played by the p-value in this case, when the equation itself is weak?

Comment: What would your conclusions be if $p\ge 0.05$?  Wouldn't any changes indicate the role played by the p-value?

Comment: If p≥0.05, then we can say that the independent var did not significantly support the response var. I am not clear about the interpretation of p-value in a regression equation.

Comment: In addition, let's bring another component, r-squared, which dictates variability in response var accounted for by the independent var. Do we determine that the regression equation can be used to predict the response var, based on the variability (value of r-squared) as well? For moderate relationship, r=.3 to .49; let's say r-squared is .49x.49, meaning 24% of the of the variation in the response variable can be explained by the independent var. Do we need to consider the variability when we are already aware of the value of r ?

Comment: When there is just one regressor, with an intercept, as seems to be assumed here, then $R^2 = r^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p-value is always the result of some statistical hypothesis test. If you are unclear about what it means, ask yourself what it is that you are actually testing. In the case of r, r is the correlation coefficient of a sample and not of the population as a whole. The hypothesis that is being tested is R=0 vs. R≠0 where R is the correlation coefficient of the whole population. The p-value tells you whether to reject R=0 and claim that R≠0, or not to reject R=0 and say that actually there is no correlation in the population (in spite of the fact that r of the sample is not 0). That's all that the p-value implies. Once you decide that R≠0 , you can do whatever you want with r or r-squared (they are equivqlent, one being the square of the other).

Comment: Got it. First I need to check for significance and then for correlation. Thanks

Comment: Please advise on my question pertaining to variability.  If we bring another component into picture, r-squared, which explains variability in response var accounted for by the independent var. Do we determine that the regression equation can be used to predict the response var, based on the variability (value of r-squared) as well? For a moderate relationship, r=.3 to .49; let's say r-squared is .49x.49, meaning 24% of the of the variation in the response variable can be explained by the independent var. Do we need to consider the variability when we are already aware of the value of r ?

Comment: Also, is there any range  stating low, moderate and high variability? For instance, how do we interpret 20%, 30% and 40% variability in a regression equation? Thanks